# How to store jquery selectable into mysql db using php

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, store, selectable

I have a grid like this http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#display-grid .

How can I store a user selected "number" into mysql db using php ?

[here is jquery selectable demo html code](http://pastebin.com/1EaujY4q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like, will save the selectednumbers each time the selection changes:

Javascript side:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var selectedNumbers = "";
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function(i) {
                if(i != 0) {
                    selectedNumbers += ",";
                 }
                 selectedNumbers += $(this).text();
            });
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url: "savenumbers.php",
                 data : {
                     numbers: selectedNumbers
                  }
            });
         }
    });
```

PHP (really simple example)

```
$numbers = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['numbers']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytablename (numbers) VALUES('" . $numbers . "')");
```

Comment: thx @Niels, can you explain little more. link to demo html code is pasted in queston.

Comment: You can just copy/paste the Javascript code. And for the php, make a new file names savenumbers.php and make a mysql_connection to the server and paste the php code, if you have a mysql table.

Comment: i don't know how to submit to php file. Can u take a look on the pasted html code in first question ? How should form look like ? thanks

Comment: You don't need a form, because I'm using an Ajax post. So people will stay on the page.